# Remove flickering from TSpeedButton

Tags: delphi

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add `TPanel` to a new VCL form and set `Align = alClient`.
2. Add `TSpeedButton` to the panel and assign some bmp image to the `Glyph` property. (Optional but makes it clearer: `Flat = True`)
3. Run the application, grab the bottom right corner of the form and move it around. The image in the `TSpeedButton` will flicker.

I read a lot about getting rid of flickering, but neither of the suggestions seem to work for a `TSpeedButton`:

- There's no `DoubleBuffered` property
- `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` can't be set, because it's not a `TWinControl` but a `TGraphicControl`
- `WM_ERASEBKGND` message isn't received

In case it is of any importance, I'm actually using `TPngSpeedButton`, but since the actual problem lies within the `TSpeedButton`, I'm using that in the example.

Is there any solution for this?

**Edit:** For some reason nobody is able to reproduce this so far, so to make sure it's not my description, here's the dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 635
    Height = 337
    Align = alClient
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 0
    object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
      Left = 64
      Top = 56
      Width = 32
      Height = 32
      Flat = True
      Glyph.Data = {
        360C0000424D360C000000000000360000002800000020000000200000000100
        180000000000000C000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483F241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483F241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483F241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483F241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483F241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241C
        ED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED24
        1CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CED241CEDCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFCC483FCC483F
        CC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC483FCC48
        3FCC483FCC483FCC483FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
    end
  end
end
```

[And this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v1wc.gif). In reality it's a little bit faster, but the captured video and gif conversion slows it down a bit.

Comment: Yes, use regular `TButton`. Anyway, I cannot reproduce in Delphi Tokyo.

Comment: See if setting "transparent" to false helps. The default is true but with a bitmap on you don't need it.

Comment: Tried in D7 and XE7, neither produces any kind of flicker as you claim. (used a `.bmp` as glyph in both attempts

Comment: My results are with XE and 10.2. I've now tried on an additional system that has Windows 10 on it. Apparently, it doesn't flicker there. But it does on my two other systems with Windows 7 on them. Both with and without Aero enabled. It also does flicker in a Windows 7 VM I have at hand. Maybe this problem only occurs with Windows 7? Whats's your system?

Comment: My system is Win7 32bit, ordinary light weight office machine, builtin display driver

Comment: I don't understand why nobody is able to reproduce it. Searching the web reveals that I'm not the only one with this problem. I've now added the dfm code and a screen capture. I mean, I'm not making this up. So even if this problem occurs only on some systems, it's still a problem. Why voting it down? :(

Comment: Have you tried setting `DoubleBuffered` on the parent of the button instead?

Comment: Still cannot reproduce the tiniest bit of flickering with your DFM example. However, I think we all know the flickering you're talking about. I've had it happen to an absolute horrible extent in a project. We gave up on it. We were never able to properly reproduce it.

Comment: @quasoft: Yes, I played around with DoubleBuffered for the panel and the form without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was actually able to reproduce it on Windows 7 with Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo.
I have had similar problems quite often and since then I've been using this settings for all `TPanel` and its descendants, which worked in this case as well.

```
Panel1.DoubleBuffered := True;
Panel1.ParentBackground := False;
```

Comment: Wow, `Panel1.ParentBackground := False` seems to be the key! Setting this propery makes the flickering go away (regardless of the Panel1.DoubleBuffered value). What kind of sorcery is this? I tried a lot, but it didn't come into my mind to try this as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both were required on my reproduction.