# Flickering TMenuItem in TPopupMenu with images

Tags: delphi

A `TMenuItem` inside a `TPopupMenu` is flickering if it contains an image.

Notice, that the whole item is flickering and not only the image area (don't mind the slightly changing colors which is a compression issue).

[image: flickering TPopupMenu]

I’ve worked on this problem for several hours now, but unfortunately cannot find a solution, or at least an explanation. This problem is similar to my last question ([Remove flickering from TSpeedButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567390/remove-flickering-from-tspeedbutton)), so I guess not everyone will be able to reproduce this problem. I can reproduce it on 3 different Windows 7 systems (2 physical, 1 VM) but not on my Windows 10 system (same as with the `TSpeedButton` flickering). Even if you can’t reproduce it, maybe you can think of a reason and solution for this.

I’ve debugged the Vcl units (mainly Vcl.Menus), thinking I can create a custom double-buffered paint method for the image. But it turns out, the painting isn’t the problem. *Reading* from `TMenuItem` canvas is!

The canvas is created in `TPopupList.WndProc`. If I remove the line `DrawMenuItem()` the flickering is gone (likewise the image). Here’s the strange part. If I access some property of the canvas instead (without drawing anything on it), the flickering is back! For example, adding the following line (instead of `DrawMenuItem()`) causes flickering, without drawing any image:

```
OutputDebugString(PChar(IntToHex(Canvas.Brush.Color)));
```

I cannot create a double-buffered solution without accessing the canvas content (copying it with `Canvas.CopyRect` or `BitBlt`) or at least reading one pixel color.

Here's a sample dfm (created with Delphi 10.2.3):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 295
  ClientWidth = 341
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PopupMenu = PopupMenu1
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Images = ImageList1
    Left = 168
    Top = 152
    object Firstline1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'First line'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
    object Secondline1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Second line'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
    object hirdline1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Third line'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Left = 96
    Top = 152
    Bitmap = {
      494C010101000500040010001000FFFFFFFFFF10FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      0000000000003600000028000000400000001000000001002000000000000010
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC483F00CC48
      3F00CC483F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED0000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED0000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED0000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED0000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241CED00241C
      ED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED00241CED0000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000424D3E000000000000003E000000
      2800000040000000100000000100010000000000800000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00FFFF000000000000FFFF000000000000
      FC07000000000000FC07000000000000FC07000000000000FC07000000000000
      FC07000000000000C007000000000000C007000000000000C07F000000000000
      C07F000000000000C07F000000000000C07F000000000000C07F000000000000
      FFFF000000000000FFFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000}
  end
end
```

Additionally, I've went through my installed applications and tried their context menus. Only a few of them were flickering, most of them weren't. Further investigation revealed, that all of the affected applications have been created with Delphi! To me, this seems like a general Delphi problem, that has always been there, but nobody cared too much about it - maybe because it doesn't affect all systems.

What’s causing this problem? Is there any proper solution or at least a workaround for this?

Comment: Hello! I often see such a drastic effect even with system menus (and EVEN without glyphs at all). So I think you have only two ways: either accept this flickering as a bug inside of WIndows 7 (don't know about another Windows) or implement your own *shortcut-menu* (in Windows therminology) and paint your items by yourself. But the last state, because of its difficulty, is only option if flickering makes you really nervious.

Comment: No repro here with W7. But tracing the code I can see (visually) that first an item is cleared (background paint), then gutter is painted, then a possible highlight background is painted, then image is drawn, then lastly text is drawn. The last one visually appears only when the DC state is restored. So theoretically flickering should be possible but it should depend on drawing stages, not accessing canvas. Did you test with an empty "DebugOutputString"? Just the time the output takes could be causing the flicker to become perceivable.